# exercise problem inLinear algebra , pg#5, Q.8

Tags: linear-algebra

in this question, "Prove that each field of characteristic zero contains a copy of the rational number field" ,i can't understand what does the "copy" mean? And if someone help me to prove this it will be appreciable

Comment: Do you know what it means for a field to have characteristic 0?

Comment: the field for which $1+1+1+...+1=0$ ,is said to be of characteristic n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the canonical ring homomorphism $\mathbb Q \to K$, which sends $1\in\mathbb Q$ to $1\in K$. This homomorphism is injective because $K$ has characteristic $0$. Hence its image is a copy of $\mathbb Q$ inside $K$.